# How can I plot points (lon/lat) over a SpatRaster map?

Tags: r, plot, r-raster, terra

I have a dataframe (ScientificName, Lon and Lat columns) called presence.

```
plot(region, col="grey", legend=F)
points(presence, pch="+", col="red")
```

I get a plot for the region but when I run the "points" line I don't get anything (no error, no plot, nothing).

I expected points of occurrence over my raster map. I made sure that my map and occurrences are in the same coord ref.

EDIT:
This is what my data looks like. I tried getting rid of the "scientificName" column and running the previous code gain but it still doesn't work and I don't get any error.

```
> show(region)
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 420, 900, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 8, 15.5, 54.5, 58  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
name        : C_01 
min value   :    0 
max value   :    0 


show(presence)
# A tibble: 1,529 × 2
   decimalLatitude decimalLongitude
             <dbl>            <dbl>
 1            55.5            10.7 
 2            55.7            12.2 
 3            55.7            11.7 
 4            55.4            10.5 
 5            56.1            10.5 
 6            55.8            11.4 
 7            55.4            11.2 
 8            56.1             9.57
 9            56.2            10.2 
10            55.9            10.1 
# ℹ 1,519 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained, reproducible example (that is, some example data generated with code). Or at least `show(region)` and `show(presence)`. Without that, there is no way in which we can help you. My guess is that you have the longitude and latitude points in the wrong order.

Comment: Mostly likely the points function is not handling the first column.  Try removing the "ScientificName" column and passing just the Longitude and Latitude columns.  Without some sample data, I can't test the recommendation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've just edited my post to add more info

Comment: I say `points()` is plotting the first columns as the longitude and the second columns as the latitude. Either rearrange the columns or use`points(presence$decimalLongitude, presence$decimalLatitude)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `presence` data frame to shapefile to add it on the raster map. You have not provided any data. So, I am using the datasets available in `terra` package.

```
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
region <- rast(f)
plot(region)

presence <- data.frame(decimalLongitude=c(6.0,6.1,6.2,6.2), 
                decimalLatitude = c(49.7,49.8,49.9,49.6))

#convert the data frame into shapefile 
m <- vect(presence, geom=c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

plot(m, add = T)
```

[image]